# app build on brunch uses hardcoded paths for app.css/app.js/... files

Tags: javascript, npm, brunch

I have installed brunch on windows via npm (`npm install brunch`)

Then I created and built new project in my www root directory (apache www root):

```
cd .../www
brunch new someproject
cd someproject
brunch build
```

When I type `localhost/someproject/public` in browser there are following errors in console log (chrome):

```
GET http://localhost/stylesheets/app.css 404 (Not Found) localhost:9
GET http://localhost/javascripts/vendor.js 404 (Not Found) localhost:10
GET http://localhost/javascripts/app.js 404 (Not Found) localhost:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So it seems that paths for those files are hardcored from root path... How I can make this work - some change in brunch config file?

I know I can use `brunch watch --server` and type `localhost:3333` but I want to use apache instead. So basically it is a problem of deploying app into production (public folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case you need to change `app/assets/index.html` paths to js / CSS.